# SQS FIFO Queue delivering message Multiple times to consumer

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-sqs

we see intermittently the messages are picked up more than one time by the consumers and processed. We have concurrent consumers waiting for message.

We are using spring to connect to the SQS FIFO queue, we have around 40 queues in SQS.
Visibilitytimeout is 30 seconds in our case. But looking at the timestamp,the messages are picked by the consumers in very close time interval (less than 30 second)

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> sqsFactory(ConnectionFactory 
 connectionFactory,                                              
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
         DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new 
         DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
         factory.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
         factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
         factory.setConcurrency("1-50");
         factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         return factory;
}
 --------Listener class----
 @Service
 public class QueueListener{
     @JmsListener(destination = "${queue.listener}", 
                    containerFactory = "sqsFactory")
      public void onMessage(Message msg) {

    try {
        msg.acknowledge();

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

      //processMsg()
 }
```

Comment: How are you verifying whether it's a message consumption issue (the same message being delivered multiple times), or a message production issue (distinct messages with the same content)? These are two different problems that can look the same at first, but require different solutions

Comment: From the application logs, it shows that code try to put  the message to SQS only once, but the same message is picked up twice, it does not happen always, may be for 1 or 2 percent of the messages

Comment: You have to be ready for these scearios with SQS where in the message is delivered more tha once, i have been experiencing this issue with Stadard and FIFO both queues. Its better to handle the scenarion in code where in you dont end up doing the stuff twice.